# Commenting on html document in a google docs manner

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for an idea how to implement commenting on HTML document like google docs does for text.

I'm loading HTML from backend and embed it into a webpage.

I was thinking about adding some tags to HTML but there's no guarantee that these tags will not break a pair of any other tags from HTML document.

E.g.

`<div>
  <p><mycustomtag>Some html </p>here</mycustomtag>
</div>`

In this example `mycustomtag` open tag is located between `p` open and close tags thus breaks `p` tag pair.

[image]

Comment: Well, it's not well-structured like that. What is the reason for that structure?

Comment: The reason is that use may select any range of html document and mark it as a comment. And there is no guarantee that it’ll be well structured part of html.

Comment: Are you using vanilla javascript, jquery, or some other library?

Comment: I’m using ReactJS. I don’t think it matters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First thoughts: you need to have some manifest for your HTML, for example Json file that will contains list of messages and for each message you can specify start of the `selectedText (index of char)` and `length(length of the selected text)`.

Comment: The main question is how to display these highlights and keep HTML consistency?

Comment: If you will have your metadata in separate file you are not going to break your HTML file, it will always be in your backend state. So, instead of getting from backend only HTML you need fetch two: HTML and metadata file. After you get them both, you need to write custom code (or use some js library) to add comments into your view on top of original HTML